# How to check network speed using cmd in Windows 7?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to check network speed of a link between my PC and a server.
I cant use any 3rd party tool like Iperf etc. Is there any way I can calculate network speed using any command on cmd?

Answer (score 0):

For batch-file I would recommend to use embedded [bitsadmin.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bits/bitsadmin-tool).
But [BitsTransfer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitstransfer/) cmdlets work better.

So I give the Powershell example:

```
$file = $env:USERPROFILE + "\Downloads\trash.bin"       #File download path
$URL =  "http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test1Mb.db"   #URL from online speed test service
$JobName = "MyJob"                      #Variable value for download job operations


Get-BitsTransfer -Name $JobName|Remove-BitsTransfer     #Clear all same jobs before operations
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $URL -Destination $file -DisplayName $JobName -Asynchronous  #Start download
$job= Get-BitsTransfer -Name $JobName               #Select our download job

While  ($job.JobState -ne "Transferred" ) {$job}        #Wait for the file transfert

if ($job.JobState -eq "Transferred" ) {
    $time = ($job.TransferCompletionTime - $job.CreationTime).TotalSeconds  #count download spend time in seconds
    $size = $job.BytesTransferred                       #count total transferred bytes
    Write-Host ("Speed = " + $size / $time /1MB + " MB/s")          #count and print speed
    $job|Complete-BitsTransfer                      #finish download job
                    }
```

- P.S. `Start-BitsTransfer` transfer type can be:  download, upload and
  uploadreply. Disk operations can take more time (caused by mechanic-
  , antivitus- , drivers-  troubles, etc.). So for proper test values
  use larger files.
- P.S.S. In this example *URL*  value can be not only HTTP, but can be SMB. Use UNC-path.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my script:

```
@echo off
:top
SET _first=%time%
ping 192.168.0.1 1 >nul
SET _second=%time%

   SET _temp=%_first:.=%
   SET _first=%_temp::=%
   SET _temp=%_second:.=%
   SET _second=%_temp::=%
set /a delay = %_second% - %_first%
echo Your internet delay is %delay%ms
pause
goto :top
```

What this should do is record the current time, ping to the router, and record the time again. Then it removes the periods and colons (so that the subtraction will work) and subtracts the two times. The only time it should fail is if this script runs over zero o'clock (12:00 a.m.). I'm not the best with batch, so I hope this works for you.

Comment: ping gives you the latency but not the throughput which is what this question is about